# How can I query only the latest iteration?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, filter

I'm wondering how to query the latest iteration of a field in my results.
For example, I write a query that'll return me this list of IDs:

```
132GBD00  
132GBD01  
59RTW900  
59RTW901  
59RTW902  
376BH200  
376BH201  
376BH202  
376BH203  
5789DD00
```

I'd like the query to to return this result:

```
132GBD01  
59RTW902  
376BH203  
5789DD00
```

Notice that the similar `IDs` differ in only the last two characters. 00 being the original and 01, 02, etc coming after. If I write a query like:

```
SELECT memid 
FROM MEMBERID
WHERE MEMBERID = ???
```

The table has dates, but I cannot search for distinct `memid` and filter by a `max(date)` because sometimes the latest iteration date is NULL. I'm trying to see if it's possible to look at a list of IDs and filter by the last two characters in the ID to see which is greater and return that.

Comment: This is an indication of a design gone wrong. You are cramming two values into a single tuple which violates 1NF and is a serious PITA to deal with. You can probably leverage ROW_NUMBER here but you will have to partition by a substring.

Comment: Probable typo: `FROM MEMBERID` and `WHERE MEMBERID = ???` is rather odd. A table name in both places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the last two numbers are sequence numbers.  You can get the most recent one with a `group by`:

```
select max(memid) as memid
from members
group by left(memid, len(memid) - 2);
```

If you wanted other columns, then you would use `row_number()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT Memid
                  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Memid, LEN(Memid) - 2) ORDER BY memid DESC) AS Rownum
             FROM MEMBERID
)
SELECT Memid
FROM cte
WHERE Rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number as below:

```
Select top(1) with ties * from Members
   Order by Row_Number() over (partition by SUBSTRING(memid, 1, len(memid)-2) order by convert(int,substring(memid, len(memid)-1, 2)) desc)
```

Or outer query as below:

```
Select MemId from (
    Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by SUBSTRING(memid, 1, len(memid)-2) order by convert(int,substring(memid, len(memid)-1, 2)) desc)
    from Members
) a Where a.RowN = 1
```

With other columns as well

Answer (score 0):

I created a temp table using your data. Here is a pretty simple way to do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Values (
    SomeValue varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '132GBD00';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '132GBD01';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '59RTW900';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '59RTW901';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '59RTW902';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '376BH200';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '376BH201';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '376BH202';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '376BH203';
INSERT INTO #Values 
SELECT '5789DD00';


SELECT DISTINCT
    LAST_VALUE(SUBSTRING(SomeValue, 1, 6)) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(SomeValue, 1, 6) ORDER BY SomeValue) AS LasID
FROM #Values
```